# Globally disable update/delete from Access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm looking to add some basic security to an Access .MDB.  What I'd like to do is query Active Directory from VBA (i have this code), then if the user isn't in the right group, turn off the allow updates, deletions, insertions, for every form in the database.  Basically, just allow readonly.

Is this possible?  How can I do this in VBA?  Is there a way to set this once in the autoexec method instead of on every form?

OR is there another way of providing simple security here?  Example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `AllowAdditions`, `AllowDeletions`, and `AllowEdits` for a single form with a procedure like this:

```
Public Sub SetFormEdit(ByVal pName As String, _
        ByVal pReadOnly As Boolean)
    Dim frm As Form

    DoCmd.OpenForm pName, acDesign
    Set frm = Forms(pName)
    frm.AllowAdditions = pReadOnly
    frm.AllowDeletions = pReadOnly
    frm.AllowEdits = pReadOnly
    DoCmd.Close acForm, pName, acSaveYes
    Set frm = Nothing
End Sub
```

To run that procedure for all your forms ...

```
Public Function SetAllFormsEdit()
    Dim blnReadOnly As Boolean
    Dim frm As Object

    'load value for blnReadOnly from your existing AD code '

    For Each frm In CurrentProject.AllForms
        SetFormEdit frm.Name, blnReadOnly
    Next frm
    Set frm = Nothing
End Function
```

Then call the `SetAllFormsEdit` function from the `RunCode` action of your `autoexec` macro.

Comment: -This looks perfect, I was looking for a global setting and completely overlooked looping through the AllForms collection.  I'll give it a try and let you know.